# Bootstrap: Input field with checkbox breaks for smaller screen sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I want to show a checkbox next to an input. On larger screens it works:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <form class="py-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Noise level</label>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <input type="number" class="form-control">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" id="auto" class="form-check-input ml-2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="auto">auto</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <small class="form-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in leo ut turpis elementum dictum.</small>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

However, when you click "Run code snippet" and "Full page" and try it out in a narrow browser window, it looks like this:

[image: broken]

How can I fix the broken checkbox label?

Comment: Is there a reason you are relying on `form-inline` instead of the Bootstrap Grid here?

Comment: @RobertC No reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `ml-2` from the checkbox and add `mr-2` for input so that the margin-left does not break it.

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="py-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Noise level</label>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <input type="number" class="form-control mr-2">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="auto">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="auto">auto</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <small class="form-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in leo ut turpis elementum dictum.</small>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Сode sample:** https://www.codeply.com/go/sQ8jFKLwRe

Answer (score 2):

Another solution I found is to add the class `form-check-inline` to the `div.form-check`:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <form class="py-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Noise level</label>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <input type="number" class="form-control">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" id="auto" class="form-check-input ml-2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="auto">auto</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <small class="form-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in leo ut turpis elementum dictum.</small>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several options you could take in lieu of relying on `form-inline` though they all rely on the Bootstrap Grid:

(1) Use `input-group` with `input-group-append`

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Noise level</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <div class="input-group-text">
        <input type="checkbox" id="auto" class="mr-2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="auto">auto</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in leo ut turpis elementum dictum.</small>
</div>
```

(2) Use *just* the Grid

```
<div class="form-group form-row align-items-center">
  <label class="col-12">Noise level</label>
  <div class="col-10">
    <input type="number" class="form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="col-2 text-center">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" id="auto2" class="form-check-input">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="auto2">auto</label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12">
    <small class="form-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in leo ut turpis elementum dictum.</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

(3) Similar to (1) you can still use `input-group` but omit `input-group-text` to avoid the gray square wrapper:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Noise level</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <div class="p-2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="auto3" class="mr-2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="auto3">auto</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <small class="form-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in leo ut turpis elementum dictum.</small>
</div>
```

You can view the output of all 3 options at: https://www.bootply.com/VnuTFC0YrX

Which one is *best* is probably a matter of preference and purpose.  I respond best to the first option as the manner in which `input-group` combines the form elements creates a deeper sense of the two items being connected.

Answer (score 0):

because of the bootstrap class `.form-inline` have `flex-flow: row wrap`; simply you can override it in your css and make it `flex-flow: row nowrap`; and add class `.mr-2` to the input to give margin right

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <form class="py-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Noise level</label>
      <div class="form-inline" style="flex-flow: row nowrap;">
        <input type="number" class="form-control mr-2">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" id="auto" class="form-check-input">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="auto">auto</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <small class="form-text text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus in leo ut turpis elementum dictum.</small>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```